# Running a Java window within a C# Application

Tags: c#, java, window

I have been searching around to see if there was anyway to run a java executable within a c# program, but I cannot seem to work it out or were to begin.

Comment: As in I wanted it to be my application then the java executable in the middle.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to integrate a Java frame into a C# program, take a look at [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net), that is :

> an implementation of Java for Mono and the Microsoft .NET Framework.

otherwise you can simply call the java app packed into a jar file in this way :

```
        Process proc = new Process();  
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();  
        startInfo.Arguments = @"-jar javaapp.jar";  
        startInfo.FileName = "java";  
        proc.StartInfo = startInfo;  
        proc.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/) which provides your exact requirement I guess.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this and report back :)